# JQuery Select event not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a Jquery function that shows a dropdown list while you type (fetched from active directory) and I want it to redirect to a new page when you click on one of these dropdown options. Everything works except the select event, any ideas on my mistake?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#searchName").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $("#loadingImg").show();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/SearchUserWhileTyping",
                type: "GET",
                data: { name: $("#searchName").val() },
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        //alert(item.distinguishedName);
                        return {
                            label: item.displayName
                        }
                    }));
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $("#loadingImg").hide();
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    alert(ui.item.distinguishedName);
                    var link = '@Url.Action("ShowUserInfo", "Home", new { distinguishedName = "value"})';
                    link = link.replace("value", ui.item.distinguishedName);
                    window.location.href = link;
                    //window.location.href = Url.ActionLink("Test", "ShowUserInfo", "Home", new {distinguishedName = ui.item.distinguishedName});
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 4
    })
});
```

Also, distinguishedName and displayName are properties from my model class ADProperties which contains properties of Active Directory users.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You've put the select option on your ajax call, not the autocomplete options...

Comment: What does this have to do with c#?

Comment: Yeah thanks I just realized. Now I have another problem is that the ui.item.distinguishedName has no value, any idea how to take retrieve that value?
Well I'm using asp.net project with c# and my classes are in c# so I thought it'd be worth mentioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally what worked for me was using a variable to retrieve the value I wanted. Also made the fixes suggested by Taplar:

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
            var distName = [];
            var dispName = [];
            $("#searchName").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $("#loadingImg").show();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Home/SearchUserWhileTyping",
                        type: "GET",
                        data: { name: $("#searchName").val() },
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                distName[item.displayName] = item.distinguishedName;
                                //distName.push(item.distinguishedName);
                                dispName.push(item.displayName);
                                return {
                                    label: item.displayName
                                }
                            }));
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                            $("#loadingImg").hide();
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    var res;
                    var index = 0;
                    alert(ui.item.label);
                    $.each(dispName, function (key, value) {
                        if (ui.item.label == value)
                            res = distName[value];
                    });

                    //alert(disName.distinguishedName);
                    var link = '@Url.Action("ShowUserInfo", "Home", new { distinguishedName = "value"})';
                    link = link.replace("value", res);
                    window.location.href = link;
                    //window.location.href = Url.ActionLink("Test", "ShowUserInfo", "Home", new {distinguishedName = ui.item.distinguishedName});
                },
                minLength: 4
            })
        });
```